# Get rid of gray rectangle overlay on PageView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

does anybody know how to get rid of this gray overlay that you get when you long-press on BottomNavigationBarItem. It is really frustrating and it kills my esthetics?

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a `BottomNavigationBarItem` displays a [tooltip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem/tooltip.html). If you don't set it, value of `label` is used, which in your case seems to be empty.
Add an explicit tooltip with empty string to every `BottomNavigationBarItem` in order to disable tooltip:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  tooltip: '',
),
```

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly, thanks for the explanation. Thank You!!